# Accessing Thymeleaf Spring Boot application.properties when using webpack devserver

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, webpack-dev-server

I can access the relevant property values from application.properties when browsing to the application on http://localhost:8081, but not using the webpack devserver via http://localhost:9090.

**webpack.dev.js (devserver)**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {

    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'src/main/resources/templates/index.html',
          title: 'Example Application'
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
          Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
      })
    ],
    .
    .

    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 9090,
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8081',
                secure: false,
                prependPath: false
            }
        },
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:9090/'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
 });
```

**index.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
       .
       .
      <script th:inline="javascript">
        var SERVICES_URL = [[${servicesUrl}]];
        var MAPS_URL = [[${mapsUrl}]];
      </script>     
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="react"></div>
      <script src="/bundle.js"></script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
services.url=https://example1.com
maps.url=https://example2.com
```

When accessing the variable SERVICES_URL in any javascript file while using the webpack devserver, I get the following error because the variable is not getting assigned the value by Thymeleaf.

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

I assume that it doesn't work on the webpack devserver because its only serving up the frontend code vs the embedded tomcat server, which is serving the server-side code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to remove the HtmlWebpackPlugin from the webpack configuration file so that the index is not loaded from the resources file but from the response after Thymeleaf has done its thing.

```
   plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
//    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
//       template: 'src/main/resources/templates/index.html',
//       title: 'Example Application'
//    }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: 'jquery',
         jQuery: 'jquery',
         'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
         Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
      })
  ],
```